# CSS pseudo ::after on select box does not open options

Tags: html, css

I have styled on a select box. The right hand side has arrow icon.

[image]

This has styled by pseudo ::after. However when I click this icon, the selectbox does not open.

The style is

```
.form-field__select:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 11px;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    margin: -5px 0 0;
    border: 2px solid #838F9D;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(
45deg
);
    transform: rotate(
45deg
);
}
```

I have searched google and ofcause here. Unfortunately I could not find a solution. Is there any workaround for this?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried, its working as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/3wLksgm8/

Comment: Can you please upload html also ?

Comment: The pseudo classes cannot be used for events such as click, hover, focus etc. If you are creating a custom select box, use some other element such as span or something. That would work.

Comment: Thank you for reply guys

I have tried fiddle and noticed probably some other style is affecting. And I found it! 
There are two problem. 
1) pseudo ::after was setup wrapper div that contains <select> tag. 
2) far parent was setup -webkit-appearance: none;

I setup as @Nitheesh provided and removed '-webkit-appearance' then it worked. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reply @Nitheesh, @codeuix, @Abin Thaha

I have tried fiddle as @Nitheesh provided, and noticed style setup wrongly also other style was preventing.

There are two problems.

1. pseudo ::after was setup wrapper div that contains  tag.

[image]

2. parent tag was styled with `-webkit-appearance: none;`

I put ::after style with  tag, and removed `-webkit-appearance` then it worked.

Thank you !